# Apple ipad old password

Tags: ipad

Have had my iPad reset due to being disabled and when setting it up again it has asked for the old password to restore some apps.I am not sure exactly what it is so can I find out somehow as I don't want it to disable again?

Comment: iCloud, app store, or lock screen password?

Comment: To restore some apps it should be AppStore... If you had used some paid Apps on your iPad, it can be usefull to try to log in again... If not, you can just create another AppStore account, remember the password and forget the older one.